# What are good practices regarding shared libraries on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

I recently read a lot about shared libraries on Linux, and here is what I learnt:

- A shared library should embed a `soname` including its major version number. Something like: `libfoo.so.1`
- Its real filename should also include a minor version number. Something like: `libfoo.so.1.0`
- When the library file is copied to, say `/usr/local/lib`, if `ldconfig` is run, it will read the `soname` and create a symlink named `libfoo.so.1` pointing to `libfoo.so.1.0`.
- If one wants to use this library for its developments it should first create a symlink without any version number to the real file, say `libfoo.so` pointing to `libfoo.so.1.0`. This is usually done by the *development* package (when the library is packaged).

Is this correct ?

Comment: You are correct but see http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/libtool-2.1a/libtool_6.html anyhow :)

Comment: @Navi: Several links, man pages (`ldconfig`, `gcc`) and I experienced myself. This link was helpful: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: Do not hesitate to post this as an answer (after all you perfectly answer my question ;)).

Comment: I'll pass on that since actually one part I'd have to explain is when you should bump your library version, a good answer should include that :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Suggested reading:

Ulrich Drepper's How to write shared libraries: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

Ulrich Drepper's Good Practices in library design, implementation, and maintenance: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/goodpractice.pdf

dsohowto is much more detailed. goodpractice is a quick read.