# How to build the elf interpreter (ld-linux.so.2/ld-2.17.so) as static library?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, elf, linux-from-scratch

I apologize if my question is not precise because I don't have a lot
of Linux related experience. I'm currently building a Linux from
scratch (mostly following the guide at linuxfromscratch.org version
7.3). I ran into the following problem: when I build an executable it
gets a hardcoded path to something called ELF interpreter.

```
readelf -l program
```

shows something like

```
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

I traced this library ld-linux-so.2 to be part of glibc. I am not very
happy with this behaviour because it makes the binary very unportable
- if I change the location of /lib/ld-linux.so.2 the executable no
longer works and the only "fix" I found is to use the patchelf utility
from NixOS to change the hardcoded path to another hardcoded path. For
this reason I would like to link against a static version of the ld
library but such is not produced. And so this is my question, could
you please explain how could I build glibc so that it will produce a
static version of ld-linux.so.2 which I could later link to my
executables. I don't fully understand what this ld library does, but I
assume this is the part that loads other dynamic libraries (or at
least glibc.so). I would like to link my executables dynamically, but
I would like the dynamic linker itself to be statically built into
them, so they would not depend on hardcoded paths. Or alternatively I
would like to be able to set the path to the interpreter with
environment variable similar to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, maybe
LD_INTERPRETER_PATH. The goal is to be able to produce portable
binaries, that would run on any platform with the same ABI no matter
what the directory structure is.

Some background that may be relevant: I'm using Slackware 14 x86 to
build i686 compiler toolchain, so overall it is all x86 host and
target. I am using glibc 2.17 and gcc 4.7.x.

Comment: I believe it is a bad idea to change the ELF program interpreter (unless you are a Linux &  binutils guru); it is built with Glibc. You could try something else (e.g. [MUSL-Libc](http://musl-libc.org)...). Why do you want to change it? To what dynamic loader?? If you don't want to depend on its location and existence (which is a bad idea), give up dynamic linking and have only statically linked programs. And the dynamic linker `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is statically built (but still a shared library, not using any external library except the kernel provided VDSO).

Comment: Dynamic linking is meant to be dynamic, not to depend on static location. This [hardwired] approach is completely wrong. I want to fix it in my system. And the solution is easy I'm just not familiar enough with all the aspects to fix it myself.

Comment: Then, patch the kernel to fit your needs. Then you'll have to patch the toolchain (compiler & linker) to obey them. Indeed, all this is free software and you can improve it.

Comment: Sure, that's the next thing to do, but I was hoping Linux was more evolved after so many decades and that's why I'm asking. I didn't expect to face such [can't find the right word] obstacles.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the best place to discuss Linux kernel design, or linker features. Use more specialized forums for that.

Comment: What you view as an obstacle is considered a major improvement over previous `a.out` solutions of the 1990s. And ELF is not Linux specific. Solaris (and probably AIX) use it likewise.

Answer (score 12):

> I would like to be able to set the path to the interpreter with environment variable similar to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, maybe LD_INTERPRETER_PATH.

This is simply not possible. Read carefully (and several times) the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) & [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) man pages and the Linux [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)  &  [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) specifications. And also the kernel code doing `execve`.

The ELF interpreter is responsible for dynamic linking. It has to be a file (technically a statically linked ELF shared library) at some *fixed* location in the file hierarchy (often `/lib/ld.so.2` or `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`)

<sup>The old `a.out` format from the 1990s had a builtin dynamic linker, partly implemented in old Linux 1.x kernel. It was much less flexible, and much less powerful.</sup>

The kernel enables, by such (in principle) arbitrary dynamic linker path, to have various dynamic linkers. But most systems have only one. This is a good way to parameterize the dynamic linker. If you want to try another one, install it in the file system and generate ELF executables mentioning that path.

<sup>With great pain and effort, you might make your own `ld.so`-like dynamic linker implementing your `LD_INTERPRETER_PATH` wish, but that linker still has to be an ELF shared library sitting at some *fixed* location in the file tree.</sup>

If you want a system not needing any files (at some predefined, and wired locations, like `/lib/ld.so`, `/dev/null`, `/sbin/init` ...), you'll need to build all its executable binaries statically. You may want (but current Linux distributions usually don't do that) to have a few statically linked executables (like `/sbin/init`, `/bin/sash`...) that will enable you to repair a system broken to the point of not having any dynamic linker.

<sup>BTW, the `/sbin/init` -or `/bin/sh` - path is wired *inside the kernel* itself. You may pass some argument to the kernel at boot load time -e.g. with GRUB- to overwrite the default. So even the kernel wants some files to be here!</sup>

As I commented, you might look into [MUSL-Libc](http://musl-libc.org/) for an alternative Libc implementation (providing its own dynamic linker). Read also about [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) and [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) and [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd).

In practice, accept the fact that modern Linuxes and Unixes are expecting some non-empty file system ... Notice that dynamic linking and shared libraries are a huge progress (it was much more painful in the 1990s Linux kernels and distributions).

Alternatively, define your own binary format, then make a kernel module or a [binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt) entry to handle it.

BTW, most (or all) of Linux is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can improve it (but this will take months -or many years- of work to you). Please share your improvements by publishing them.

Read also [Drepper's Hwo to Write Shared Libraries](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) paper; and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4757121/841108).

Comment: Defining my own binary format doesn't seem exactly portable. Instead of doing all this I could just expose some API in the kernel that will be able to override the hardcoded location (and possibly name) and expose this API to a user program that will be able to configure the location by simply invoking the program from shell... very much like setting LD_INTERPRETER_PATH, but better because the userspace program will be able to be restricted to root or something like that . No need to make everything static or rewrite everything.

Comment: Have fun spending time doing that. Perhaps you would encounter some unexpected issues when building the thousands of Linux programs which uses (collectively) all the intricacies enabled by ELF.

Comment: The interpreter can be a relative path.

Comment: If the interpreter is a relative path, I believe this opens some cybersecurity concerns

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. In my case I want to bundle my application with a different GLIBC than comes system installed. Since ld-linux.so must match the GLIBC version I can't simply deploy my application with the according GLIBC. The problem is that I can't run my application on older installations that don't have the required GLIBC version.

The path to the loader interpreter can be modified with --dynamic-linker=/path/to/interp. However, this needs to be set at compile time and therefore would require my application to be installed in that location (or at least I would need to deploy the ld-linux.so that goes with my GLIBC in that location which goes against a simple xcopy deployment.

So what's needed is an $ORIGIN option equivalent to what the -rpath option can handle. That would allow for a fully dynamic deployment.

Given the lack of a dynamic interpreter path (at runtime) leaves two options:

a) Use patchelf to modify the path before the executable gets launched.
b) Invoke the ld-linux.so directly with the executable as an argument.

Both options are not as 'integrated' as a compiled $ORIGIN path in the executable itself.

Comment: (rant) I believe xcopy refers to MS-DOS.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that $ORIGIN isn't handled. Yes, it's sad.