# chroot "no such file or directory" prints wrong missing file

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, chroot

I know similar questions were asked here a billion times, but different to those I got my system working. I just get the wrong error-message when I break it (and I want to debug another issue using these, so it's critical they work).

Starting with the working system:

```
$ tree
.
├── bin
│   └── bash
├── lib
│   ├── libc.so.6
│   ├── libdl.so.2
│   └── libtinfo.so.6
└── lib64
    └── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$ sudo chroot . /bin/bash
bash-5.0#
```

As we'd expect everything to run the bash is there and the bash runs.

Now when I remove anything inside the `lib` folder, I get an error telling me the library is missing:

```
$ rm -f lib/libdl.so.2
$ sudo chroot . /bin/bash
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Also as expected. However, when I remove `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` inside the `lib64` folder:

```
$ rm -f lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$ sudo chroot . /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

It's telling me `/bin/bash` is missing. The message is identical to when I actually delete it.

```
$ rm -f bin/bash
$ sudo chroot . /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

So for some reason it thinks the bash is missing when actually, what I assume is the dynamic linker, is missing. I assume this is because it's using this linker to load the elf in the first place, but that doesn't make the message more correct.

I even checked when I actually prevent `bash` it from finding `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` by running it in `qemu` on a different system I get the correct error message:

```
<some arm system>$ qemu-x86_64 -L /tmp/nowhere bin/bash
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

Is this a bug? Is there some option to tell `chroot` to not behave like this and print the actually missing file? Is there some magic in this file? What is going on here?

**TLDR**: Why does `chroot` tell me the executable is missing when actually `lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does `chroot` tell me the executable is missing when actually
> `lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is?

assuming you are using `chroot` program from GNU coreutils, we can look at the code to understand what is going on (hoping the "magic" will go away). here a [github mirror of chroot.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/chroot.c).

if we search for the string in the error message `failed to run command`, we immediately find the (only) line of code that prints it:

```
  /* Execute the given command.  */
  execvp (argv[0], argv);

  int exit_status = errno == ENOENT ? EXIT_ENOENT : EXIT_CANNOT_INVOKE;
  error (0, errno, _("failed to run command %s"), quote (argv[0]));
  return exit_status;
}
```

as you can see, it's printed after the `execvp()` system call. `execvp()` is (one variant of) the system call that allows to execute a program (`/bin/bash` in your case). `execvp()` **does not return** if the execution of the program was successful because:

> The  `exec()` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

it returns **only** in case of error and sets `errno` appropriately.

the code then inspects `errno` to decide the exit status:

```
int exit_status = errno == ENOENT ? EXIT_ENOENT : EXIT_CANNOT_INVOKE;
```

and finally prints the error:

```
error (0, errno, _("failed to run command %s"), quote (argv[0]));
```

as you can see, `argv[0]` is **always** printed after `failed to run command` (`/bin/bash` in your case i.e. the program it tried to `exec`ute in a chroot environment).

`errno` is the error number "returned" by `execvp()` and determines what gets printed after (`error()` is defined as follows on my system):

```
/* Print a message with `fprintf (stderr, FORMAT, ...)';
   if ERRNUM is nonzero, follow it with ": " and strerror (ERRNUM).
   If STATUS is nonzero, terminate the program with `exit (STATUS)'.  */

extern void error (int __status, int __errnum, const char *__format, ...)
```

`No such file or directory` is error number `ENOENT` and is "returned" by `execvp()` and friends when:

> **ENOENT** The file pathname or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist.

("ELF interpreter" is a synonymous for dynamic linker [I guess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17924002/13527856))

`chroot` can't actually know what *really* went wrong, it can merely report what `execvp()` put in `errno` and I think this is the reason why the error is vague and a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does chroot tell me the executable is missing when actually lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is?

Executables are not run by themselves.

It's similar to shell scripts - you have `#!/bin/sh` and the file has executable permission, so you do `./file` and it really runs `/bin/sh ./file`.

When you do `./file` and file is ELF file with `PT_INTERP`, the file from `PT_INTERP` header is taken and is run. So what really happens, you are really running `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./file` for (almost) every possible executable on your system. You can do it on your system - `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/bash` will run Bash.

So kernel reads `/bin/bash`, sees it's an ELF file, reads `PT_INTERP`, and runs `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Because `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` does not exist, kernel sets `errno` to `ENOENT`.

Then `chroot` program inspects `errno`, and prints a message `printf("Failed to run command <that command>: <error description>`. `chroot` is not aware that the kernel couldn't find the program interpreter or the executable itself, it doesn't know. `chroot` just prints the error description.