# What will happen if my process not defined a variable but it is used as a extern variable in a shared library?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have 2 process A and B. Both process shared same shared object file called common_add.so

I defined the variable g_test_variable in process A.

But if i not define the variable g_test_variable  in process B and open the common_add.so file using dlopen & dlsym and invoke the add_double function which is not using g_test_variable variable ,will i hit any issue ?

```
/*
 * File Name : common.c
 * This file packaged as part of common_add.so
 */
extern int_32 g_test_variable; //declaration
int add_int(int a, int b)
{
   if(g_test_variable)
      printf("somthing");

      return a+b;
}

double add_double(double a, double b)
{
      return a-b;
}
```

Comment: That's what I call over-commented code ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba:) . sorry. modified the code.

Comment: Processes are running (some executable program). They don't define variables. Variables exist only at the source code level.

Comment: What is the exact motivation of the question? What is the real context? It might smell like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should **edit your question** to *improve* it

Comment: sure. i will add more details in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(I am speaking for Linux systems)</sup>

So you have a program *aa* (running in process A) and a program bb (running in process B). Both are using the `common_add.so`

But if *aa* does not define the symbol `g_test_variable`  (in some global [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) symbol table) its [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) of `common_add.so`  would fail.

How and when that happens may depend how is the dynamic linking done.

If you are using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) you'll better pass `RTLD_NOW` to avoid lazy linking. Then `dlopen` would fail and `dlerror` is giving a useful message.

If you pass the default `RTLD_LAZY`  to `dlopen` it could happen that the error would trigger only on the first call to `add_int` or even to the apparently unrelated `add_double` (but details may vary with implementations)

(don't forget to compiler the `common.c`  with `-fPIC`  for the `common_add.so` plugin, and link both main `aa` & `bb` programs with `-rdynamic`)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757370/841108) and read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

I recommend using `RTLD_NOW`  to catch at early `dlopen` time such errors. Of course, you cannot expect the program to work if an undefined symbol is referenced! (So you should require the main program to define `g_test_variable` ...). You could consider declaring your `g_test_variable`  as a [weak symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) in the plugin (but I generally do not recommend such tricks).